# Rails Backbone App Showing Nothing -- Including Errors

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js

I've been working through thoughtbot's Learn Backbone.js on Rails, and I can't even get the beginning test application to work, but I'm also getting no Javascript Errors in the console.

Here's my tasks index.haml file

```
- content_for :javascript do
  - javascript_tag do
    ExampleApp.initialize({ tasks: <%== @tasks.to_json %> });
```

My initializer file:

```
var ExampleApp = {
  Models: {},
  Collections: {},
  Views: {},
  Routers: {},
  initialize: function() {
    var tasks = new ExampleApp.Collections.Tasks(data.tasks);
    new ExampleApp.Routers.Tasks({ tasks: tasks });
    Backbone.history.start();
  }
};
```

models / task.js

```
var Task = Backbone.Model.extend({});
```

collections / tasks.js

```
var Tasks = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Task,
    url: '/tasks'
});
```

routers / tasks.js

```
ExampleApp.Routers.Tasks = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "": "index"
    },

    index: function() {
        alert('test');
        // var view = new ExampleApp.Views.TaskIndex({ collection: ExampleApp.tasks });
        // $('body').html(view.render().$el);
    }
});
```

And here's proof that I'm calling all of the files (I think):

```
<script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/underscore.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/backbone.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/backbone-support/support.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/backbone-support/composite_view.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/backbone-support/swapping_router.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/backbone-support.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/example_app.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/easing.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/modernizr.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/models/task.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/collections/tasks.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/views/task_view.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/views/tasks.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/views/tasks_index.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/routers/tasks.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/tasks/index.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/tasks/task.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Any thoughts?  I'm pretty new to both Rails and Backbone, so I'm not really sure where the error is, and the console isn't helping me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you see the `ExampleApp.initialize` code when you View Source?

You need to have a `<%= yield :javascript %>` somewhere in your layout for this example to work.

Comment: Great!  Now I am at least getting errors... but the error is that data isn't defined, although it clearly is in my view, right?

Comment: Oh, okay that was my bad.  I half-reverted to my original program, but it was still referencing half-complete code.  This worked.  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Follow below structure to get backbone working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Blog2</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```